# How can I remove my faucet valve cartridge?

Tags: faucet, stuck, cartridge

I have Symons Callie SLW-7112-RP faucet and recently there is a water leakage on both hot and cold water. It is clear that the valve cartridges need to be replaced. I followed the instruction and replaced the cold water valve cartridge. But at the hot water side the cartridge seems stuck and can't be removed easily. I attached few images to show the situation.

[image]

- above is the cartridge without the handle ad cap

[image]

- above is the instruction guide shows that the cartridge is screwed into the control valve and this is the stuck point, I can't remove it out from the control valve. I have used WD 40 and no help

[image]

- above just shows that the instruction says how easy to remove the cartridge from the control valve base. I think I need some tool to hold the base. Currently when I turn the cartridge, the whole parts is truing.

Any suggestion or recommendation on tooling is appreciated.

Comment: There are other penetrating oils that work better than WD-40. PB Blaster is one. Your local auto-parts store will have a good variety of penetrating oil-type products, you may need to try more than one. You'll also want to be sure to use plenty and give it lots of time to work. You may need several applications. Also, just to be sure, you're using a wrench above and below the counter to hold the two nuts and are turning against the wrenches, right?

Answer (score 1):

As already suggested you're going to need a good penetrating oil with several applications over time.
As you've discovered the problem is going to be holding the valve in place while you try to get enough torque to loosen the cartridge. Typically most valves will have flat surfaces built into the valve body to enable you to stabilise the valve with a wrench while loosening the cartridge. In the pictures you provided I don't see an obvious place to hold the valve with a wrench. It appears that both the top and underneath mounting nuts rotate.
I believe your best recourse is to tighten the faucet onto the counter as firmly as possible using wrenches above and below the counter - which may require two people. You can then put one wrench on the mounting retainer above the counter applying clockwise pressure while you turn the cartridge with another wrench in a counter-clockwise direction.

Comment: This is the correct answer IMO. The faucet is not properly fastened to the deck. Now, if it were me I would tighten it to the deck as @HoneyDo suggests, AND I would *still* have a helper under the sink holding the valve body whilst I unscrewed the cartridge from the top.